# How can I create a Triadiagonal Matrix on Python, without numpy and with user's input?

Tags: python, numeric

I got a homework for numerical analysis. I need to create a matrix, it needs to be tridiagonal, code will ask for how many coulmns there will be, and what will be de values. And I shouldn't use numpy etc.

I researched it a lot, but no answers. Still trying to write it. Looking for some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example of the expected user input and the result you want to get for it?

Comment: Apart from expected input/output: What have you tried after all this research? What unexpected result did your code, which you should post, deliver?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzvK353x2tQNK9ukDrK-IA9qy_tiWycC/view?usp=sharing) This is the matrix I need to create, inputs should be, N and for this N; R1, R2, ... RN. I'm new at python, so there is not much thing to show you :(

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), show what you have tried and what is the result of your research.

Comment: I think you want an alternative to [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/cbellei/8ab3ab8551b8dfc8b081c518ccd9ada9)??

Comment: @Mr.Hobo not sure. I didn't quite understand that code. Is there only 4 values? There should be N times values, and NxN triadiagonal matrix. I'm sorry, if I look like someone just wants his problem to be solved. But I'm really new in python. I'm learning at the sametime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @PharaohOfParis.
I've changed your code a little. Now it works perfect!

```
def tridiagonal(n):
  values1 = []
  values2 = [0]
  print("Enter R values ")
  for i in range(0, n):
    values1.append(float(input()))

  for i in range(0, n):
    values2.append(values1[i])

  print(values1)
  print(values2)

  M = [ [0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) ]
  for k in range(n-1):
    M[k][k] =values1[k]+values2[k]
    M[k][k+1] = -values1[k+1]
    M[k+1][k]= -values1[k+1]
  M[n-1][n-1]= values1[n-1]+values2[n-1]
  print(M)

tridiagonal(5)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel you get the response you were looking for, you can "accept the response" in the panel in the left of the message so other people looking for the same question may know, or/& if the answer helped you, you can put "This answer is helpful" also in the same panel.

Comment: I can't select "accept the response", because I'm new :D Can you do it for me?

Comment: No I can't. But it's ok :) Just remembering you in case you forget.

Answer (score 0):

I did it only for a square matrix (dimensions: (n+1,n+1)). In the following code, a is the diagonal, b the diagonal above and c the diagonal under.

```
def tridiagonal(n,a,b,c):
    M = [ [0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) ]
    for k in range(n):
        M[k][k] = a
    for k in range(n-1):
        M[k][k+1] = b
        M[k+1][k]=c
    return(M)
```

EDIT: The 2 loops can be grouped into one:

```
def tridiagonal(n,a,b,c):
    M = [ [0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) ]
    for k in range(n-1):
        M[k][k] = a
        M[k][k+1] = b
        M[k+1][k]=c
    M[n-1][n-1]=a
    return(M)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's something like that. But, there should be N times values. Not only 3(a, b, c) I'll try to change your code to N values, hope I'll thanks man

Comment: PharaohOfParis, you should edit the answer, not post another question

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment and seeing your example in the link, here another code, where L1, L2 and L3 are the 3 lists representing the diagonal, the diagonal above and the diagonal under:

```
def tridiagonal(n,L1,L2,L3):
    M = [ [0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n) ]
    for k in range(n-1):
        M[k][k] = L1[k]
        M[k][k+1] = L2[k]
        M[k+1][k]= L3[k]
    M[n-1][n-1]= L1[n-1]
    return(M)
```

You just have to define the 3 lists with your particular values.